Reference Method Change Listener not removed
When I add a change listener to an JavaFx Object Property by method reference and then try to remove that same change listener, it still seems to be registered as listener. Is this intended behaviour or a bug?
In the below example Hello World! is printed twice, I would expect it would print only once.
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    b.addListener(App::test);
    b.set(true);
    b.removeListener(App::test);
    b.set(false);
}

static void test(Object b, Object o, Object n) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
}


It's never guaranteed that Foo::bar is equal to Foo::bar, or for any other lambda either.

what you described is neither intended behaviour nor a bug. Each App::test is eventually creating a new intance (each) - you added one instance and tried to remove a second one -- similar to doing addListener(new Listener() { /*...*/ }); and later  removeListener(new Listener() { /*...*/ });

Try using Subscriptions for this. It what it is designed for, and overcomes the issues with lambda listeners.

I have same result when running your code in debugger, which prints "Hello World!" twice.
The listener lambda value App::test is resolved as reference to different instances of ChangeListener for each use, so that add/remove are not matched. Replace with a variable so that you pass same value in for each call:
ChangeListener<? super Boolean> listener = App::test;
b.addListener(listener);
b.set(true);
b.removeListener(listener);
b.set(false);

=> Prints "Hello World!" once.
Note comments by Louis Wasserman and user85421 for further explanation, and see also the JavaFX21+ workaround suggested by Slaw below which uses b.subscribe(Consumer|BiConsumer). Note that these consumer callbacks for subscribe do not pass in the source b which means you couldn't use same listener for multiple properties.

amazing, thank you for solving it. This was riddling me a long time.

@Josephus87 Just to note, another option is to do var sub = b.subscribe(...), then later do sub.unsubscribe() when appropriate. Though that requires JavaFX 21+. Also, either way you need to keep a reference to the something (i.e., the listener or the subscription).
